# Invalid Handle when using a single HANDLE with two calls of ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c, handle, readprocessmemory, openprocess

I'm just starting to learn about Windows API and I want to make a simple program which read values in a given process.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h> 

void printError();

int main()
{
    int *buffer;

    // process input
    unsigned int pid = 0;
    printf("process ID : ");
    scanf("%d", &pid);
    getchar();
    HANDLE authorisation = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    if(authorisation == NULL)
    {
        printf("OpenProcess Failed. GetLastError = %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }   

    // adress memory input
    int *memoryAddress = 0x0;
    printf("memory address to read (in hexadecimal) : ");
    scanf("%p", &memoryAddress);
    getchar();
    printf("Reading from address : %p", memoryAddress);
    if(ReadProcessMemory(authorisation, (LPCVOID)memoryAddress, &buffer, 8, 
    NULL))
    {
        printf("\nptr2int = %p\n", buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        printError();    
    }

    int varInt = 0;
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    // GetLastError return 6 : Invalid Handle 
    if(ReadProcessMemory(authorisation, (LPCVOID)buffer, &varInt, 
    sizeof(int), NULL))
    {
        printf("varInt = %d\n", varInt);
    }
    else
    {
        printError();
    }

    printf("Press ENTER to quit");
    getchar();

    return 0; 
}

void printError()
{
    printf("ReadProcessMemory Failed. GetLastError = %d", GetLastError());
    getchar();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

However, if I create a new Handle for the second call of RPM, it's working perfectly.

I read this on MSDN:

> The handle returned by the OpenProcess function can be used in any
>   function that requires a handle to a process"

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Nothing to do with Windows API. Your program is incorrect. First you attempt to read into `buffer` which is not initialized (i.e. a random address). The fact that this "works" at all is pure coincidence. I'm surprised it doesn't crash to be honest. Next, you attempt to read from `buffer`, which if anything refers to an address in your own process' address space, and as such is meaningless for `ReadProcessMemory".

Comment: You must pass sizeof(buffer) to ReadProcessMemory instead of 8.  RIght now it stores 8 bytes to a variable that can only store 4, that corrupts the stack content.  The HANDLE variable is right next to it, thus gets whacked.

Comment: ReadProcessMemory is quite unusual function to start  learning Windows API,

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed sizeof(buffer) was the correct syntax but why can "buffer" only stores 4 bytes and not 8 bytes ? I thought pointer size is always 8 bytes on 64-bit machines.

Comment: It is how you built your program that matters.  You did not mention what IDE or build tool you use, but it is pretty typical that they default to generating a 32-bit program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this:

```cpp
int *buffer;
unsigned int pid = 0;

ReadProcessMemory(authorisation, (LPCVOID)memoryAddress, &buffer, 8, NULL);
```

Let us say, the address of buffer is 0x0 and the address of pid is 0x4 because you're compiling a 32bit application and a pointer is 4 bytes.  When you call RPM you hard coded 8 bytes of size, which is overwriting pid making it invalid.  You basically Buffer Overflowed yourself.

Whenever you use ReadProcessMemory() you should always use sizeof(originalVariable) as the number of bytes argument so you never have any issue.

If you're planning to access other process's memory often you should follow this practice:

Use uintptr_t to store addresses and then compile your application to match the architecture of the target process.  When compiling for x64 it'll be 8 bytes and on x86 it'll be 4 bytes.  You could also make your own typedef if you like.

Compiling for the same architecture of the target process is helpful in many ways, which you will find out in your journey, there are several WINAPI things that are easier to work with this way.  You don't have to do this, but I highly recommend.